# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tun_recrut

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

I'm new in java and i'm trying to make simple Authentication interface.

I am trying to execute simple query using DriverManager .
Can you please help me understand what is the issue here ?

1/  MyDBConnection.java

```
package com.esprit.tunRecrut.util;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;


        public class MyDBConnection {

            /**
             * Déclaration des variables pour la connexion
             */
            private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tun_recrut";
            private String login = "root";
            private String pwd = "";
            private static MyDBConnection instance;
            public static Connection connection;

            private MyDBConnection() {
                try {
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,pwd);

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MyDBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            public static Connection getConnection() {
                return connection;
            }

            public static MyDBConnection getInstance() {
                if(instance==null)
                    instance = new MyDBConnection();
                return instance;
            }


        }
```

2/Crud.java

```
package com.esprit.tunRecrut.util;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Crud {

    MyDBConnection mc = MyDBConnection.getInstance();

    public boolean execute(String sql){
        try {
            Statement statement = mc.getConnection().createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Crud.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public ResultSet exeRead(String sql){
        try {
            Statement statement = mc.getConnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            return rs;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Crud.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

in my userDao.java

```
public User findUserByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {


     User user=null;
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_address = '" + email + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
        ResultSet rs = crud.exeRead(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {

            user = new User(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("type"), rs.getString("email_address"));

        }
        return user;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("Client controller").log(Level.SEVERE, " fail");
       // Logger.getLogger("Client DAO").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you include the JDBC jar in your project?

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I forget to import because I think it is imported automatically by netbeans

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java connectivity with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably missing mysql-connector-java-x.x.x.jar on the class path

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I forget to import because I think it is imported automatically by netbeans

Comment: Instead of answering a question that has been answered time and time again, please consider simply voting to close as duplicate and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use 'MySql' with Java you need to download 'JConnector' from MySql`s website. After that you need to set the 'Classpath'. You can use the following Commands

```
    set CLASSPATH="PathtOfMySqlConnector.jar"
```

or you can set it likr you set the bin path of Java.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

download mysql-connector from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and add it to your application class path
probably you may find this [this  tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)